# Updating a child object in React with UseState (and connecting it back to parent object)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, master-detail, use-state

I am trying to build a prototype of a master/detail type of use case in React and material-ui, using a simple list of objects, and a dialog for editing and saving an item in the list. I am updating the visit, a child of the user object, but I can't figure out how to 1. integrate the modified visit item back with the parent user object and 2. where I would do this and where I would make the api call to save the user with the updated visit object.

My test api looks like:

- GET /users/ => returns user object as: {id, name, visits:[{id, visited}]}
- PUT /users/ same object

I have 3 main components I'm working with:

1. UserVisitList.tsx (matches api of a user object with array of 'visit' objects)
2. An individual 'visit' item with edit icon button (UserVisit.tsx)
3. An Edit dialog to change one piece of state in a 'visit' (EditVisitDialog.tsx).
4. GetUser function in useEffect is just a file that returns a user object with visits.

**UserVisitList.tsx (this is placed in App.tsx)**

```
export const UserVisitList: React.FC = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>({});
  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [visit, setVisit] = useState<Visit>({});

  const onOkClick = (visit: Visit) => {
    // set the active visit?
    setVisit(visit);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const onDialogCloseClick = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // update the visited prop of active visit
    setVisit({ ...visit, visited: e.currentTarget.value });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(GetData("Jane"));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h4">Visits for {user.name}</Typography>
      <List>
        <>
          <Grid key={user.id} container>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              {user.visits?.map(function (visit: Visit, i) {
                return (
                  <UserVisit
                    key={visit.id}
                    visit={visit}
                    onEditClick={() => onOkClick(visit)}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>

          {open && (
            <EditVisitDialog
              visit={visit}
              name={user.name}
              onChangeHandler={onChangeHandler}
              onCloseHandler={onDialogCloseClick}
            ></EditVisitDialog>
          )}
        </>
      </List>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserVisitList;
```

**UserVisit.tsx:**

```
interface IVisitProp {
  visit: Visit;
  onEditClick: () => void;
}
export default function UserVisit({ visit, onEditClick }: IVisitProp) {
  return (
    <ListItem>
      <ListItemText primary={visit.visited} />
      <ListItemIcon>
        <IconButton onClick={onEditClick} edge="start">
          <EditIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        <IconButton onClick={() => console.log("del not implemented")}>
          <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </ListItemSecondaryAction>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

**EditVisitDialog.tsx:**

```
 interface IProps {
  visit: Visit;
  name?: string;
  onChangeHandler: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  onCloseHandler: () => void;
}
export default function EditVisitDialog({
  visit,
  name,
  onChangeHandler,
  onCloseHandler
}: IProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={true}>
        <DialogTitle style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          {" "}
          Edit Visit for {name}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <div>
            <label>Visited </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={onChangeHandler}
              value={visit.visited}
            />
          </div>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Grid container justify="center">
            <Button onClick={onCloseHandler} variant="outlined">
              Close
            </Button>
            <Divider />
            <Button onClick={onCloseHandler} variant="outlined">
              Save
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a feeling I'm going about this the wrong way, like how I'm handling state. I put the code in a semi-working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/master-detail-with-dialog-wnlsz . I can't get the updated visit object back to the user. And I also would like to know where I would make the call to save the user to the api once I have the visit connected back to the user.

Should I not be doing it this way?  What would be a more straight-forward way, if any, to handle this simple use case. Like I said, I don't think I'm doing it quite right. Updating data in React is very different than what I'm used to (eg getting ids via callbacks, updating dom, ajax, etc).

Comment: Your overall setup looks good!  The onChange handler should set the value in the local state because you don't want to call the API with every character that's typed.  You should call the API either in onDialogCloseClick or in a useEffect hook.  Either way you want to check the data has actually changed before calling to avoid unnecessary calls, so you want to store the fetched version as a variable somewhere.

Comment: @LindaPaiste thanks!. I still don't know how to get the visit onto the User object though. How do I attach it to the user object so I have the updated visit on the user object correctly? So say you update one of the visits to "November 10th, 2019". When they click done, I want the user object to be: {
id: x,
name: 'name',
visits: [
   {visited: "November 10th, 2019"} // changed visit
  ]
}

Answer (score 1):

#### A Bunch of Rambling Thoughts

Generally you want the components higher-up in the tree to be handling the state, which you have done a good job of.  Though I will say in this case that it's fine for a component to handle its own temporary state, like the text which has been entered but not submitted.

Let's think about what information we will need in order to make the API update call and that will guide us towards knowing what values we need to use for our state.  We are trying to update the date for a specific visit for a specific user.  So we need to know the value to set, but we also need to know both the user id and the visit id in order to update the right visit.  Potentially our API calls take the whole updated user object and the component is responsible for making a version with the altered date, but still: we need to know which visit id we are dealing with.  Right now we can get that from `visit.id`.

One way to approach this would be to store just the id of the visit that we are editing in `UserVisitList`.  Instead of having states `open` and `visit` we would have a state `editingVisitId` which is either a `number` or `null`.  We know a dialog is open if `editingVisitId !== null` and we can get the contents for the dialog by calling `user.visits.find( visit => visit.id === editingVisitId )` to find the right visit.  The `onChange` would be handled within the `EditVisitDialog`, but our `UserVisitList` would pass down on an `onClose` function which takes the new visit text value as its argument.  `EditVisitDialog` would be responsible for calling `onClose` with `e.target.value`.

But moving state up is always good, so it's fine to store the input value in `UserVisitList` like you have done.  I was at first concerned that if we did that we wouldn't be able to see if the value was changed, but I see now that we have a `user` state which is separate from the `visit` state so there's no trouble!

I've noticed that your types `User` and `Visit` have all of their fields optional (`?:`) which can lead to annoyances when we go to use those objects.  I would recommend that you remove the question marks and if you want to have an incomplete object somewhere in your app, you can use `Partial<User>` or `Partial<Visit>`; though alternatively you can keep the fields optional and type a required version with `Required<User>` or Required. When we declare that an object variable must be complete, it makes life easier because we can know for sure that the property which we are trying to access will be set.  `GetData` is an example where it doesn't make sense than an API would return an incomplete object.  It should either return a complete object or return `null` or `undefined` if called with an invalid name.

#### An Actual Answer

Your state is fine and your `onChange` event handling is fine.  Everything we need to do comes after the "Save" button is clicked.  We don't want to call the API until that point.  If we were to call the API with `onChange` it would get called with every character that they type and we would have to call it again to revert those changes if they click "Close".  We definitely do not want that.  So the "Save" event handler is for sure the right place to be calling the API.  Right now `EditVisitDialog` gets one callback which it calls on both "Close" and "Save", but we will change this to be two separate ones (`onCloseHandler` and `onSaveHandler`).

I'll start by going to `MockApi.ts` to mock an edit function so we know what our handler needs to call.  The arguments and return types are up to you since this isn't an actual API.  Do we pass the complete `User` object, or just the fields that we want to change?  Do we pass the `id` as a separate argument or do we get it from the `User` argument?  We probably return the updated `User`, but maybe we return a `boolean` indicating success or failure.  Do we have a separate method just to update a visit, or is this just a particular instance of a general user update method?  I arbitrarily decided on a signature that takes a complete `User` and returns a complete `User`.

```
async updateUser(user: User): Promise<User>
```

I came up with a handler that looks like this:

```
  const onDialogSaveClick = async () => {
    // early exit to avoid errors - but sould never be true
    if (!user) return;
    //close the open dialog
    setOpen(false);
    // validate/normalize the value here
    // apply the changed visit to user
    const editedUser = {
      ...user,
      visits: user.visits.map((v) =>
        v.id === visit.id
          ? { ...visit, visited: validateVisitText(visit.visited) }
          : v
      )
    };
    // post changes to the api and update user state with the response
    try {
      const apiResponse = await MockApi.updateUser(editedUser);
      setUser(apiResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

You can do validation of data on the frontend, backend, both, or neither.  I coded this with the idea of both in mind.  So our `onDialogSaveClick` will update the user state with the new value returned from the API even though in this case `apiResponse` will always equal `editedUser`.

This `try/catch` and `async/await` stuff is because wanted to make the mock API more like a real API with asynchronous calls.

Here's a link to my [CodeSandbox Fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/master-detail-with-dialog-forked-b6ydw?file=/src/MockApi.ts).  Mostly I changed `MockApi.ts` and `UserVisitList.tsx` with minor changes to `EditVisitDialog.tsx`.

Comment: Hi Linda, wow, thank you for the extremely helpful response. The connecting of the user and visits in a single object was my main question. I need some practice time on es6. I kept thinking there was a way to do it without mapping. 

You've given me many additional thoughts which will no doubt prove useful. This project is like a small test bed for me right now to get up to speed with React/TS, it's very much appreciated to get more out of your answer/effort. I haven't fully absorbed everything you said yet. I will go through your thoughts now and see if there's anything not clear.!

Comment: One quick thing came up re- the dummy visit object passed to ```useState<Visit>.``` I don't like that either necessarily, but you say it's required for spread. How would you do this then (ideally)?